# CORS policy error connecting to chat.postMessage in slack api with headers set and not set in React and Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, cors, axios, slack-api

I was trying to send a message to slack api using React and axios, and due to some unknown reasons I'm getting CORS policy error.

```
export const sendMessage = data => dispatch => {
    console.log(data);
    const message = {
        channel: data.currentChannelId,
        text: data.text
    };
    const token =
        "MY_TOKEN";

    const config = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
    };
    axios
        .post("https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage", JSON.stringify(message), config)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            dispatch({
                type: actionTypes.SEND_MESSAGE,
                payload: data
            });
        })
        .catch(err =>
            dispatch({
                type: actionTypes.SEND_MESSAGE,
                payload: {}
            })
        );
};
```

I have checked lot's of questions asked in here, and also contacted the support of slack, and got the following message:

> We've seen developers getting better results by making sure they're
>   not sending any headers along with their request? This can cause
>   preflight errors on our end.
>
> Could you try and see if that helps?

Of course, not sending any headers is impossible as we are sending Authorization in our headers, too.

I tried removing just `"Content-Type": "application/json"`, and again the same error occured. Also I tried changing it to `"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

No changes happens in either cases. 
I get this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Request header field content-type is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Although there are lot's of other questions, and this might be a duplicate, but none of the answers fit my problem.

Comment: @sideshowbarker dear friend, I have read your answer to the question. But, it didn't solve my problem. As you see, I have mentioned in my text that I had tried removing content-type, and nothing helped. You could at least read my text, then mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: Actually, you didn’t successfully remove the Content-Type request header. If you had, you wouldn’t still be getting a message stating, *“Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response”*

Comment: What do you mean by successfully removing it? I did it actually

Comment: I got same error and resolved by simply adding these headers on API server side

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,PUT,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization

Comment: @himanshu I'm trying this on localhost, and added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` this to the header sent by axios. Do you mean this?

Comment: @sideshowbarker will you please help me with the code? I really need it :-(

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `Content-Type` header from your request. Slack's API endpoints do not send response with `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` so the preflight fails.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I did it. Please recheck my question!